# What prepositions go with "Interview"?

Tags: difference, preposition

> ***Auf*** einem Interview mit Revolverheld.
>
> ***In*** einer Interview mit Revolverheld.

I read ***in*** einem Interview alot, but not as much as ***auf*** einem Interview and ***auf*** is the same as ***bei***. Can one also say ***bei*** einem Interview ?

What ist the difference?

Comment: You do not give complete sentences as examples, so it is hard to tell what the expressions are supposed to mean. I doubt however that you will find occurrences of “auf einem Interview” except where the “auf” belongs to some other construction.

Comment: **In** einem Interview mit Revolverheld beruht sich der Frontsänger **auf** einem Interview **bei** dem er sagte, dass...

Comment: Context is everything. The first sentence in your question is simply wrong.

Comment: @Em1... "Worauf basiert deine Abneigung gegen Deutsche Musik?" "Auf einem Interview mit Revolverheld."... indeed, context is king.

Comment: When googling "auf einem Interview" I only find cases where auf belongs a previous verb ("beruht auf" and "basierend auf") and some gibberish. @Em1: do you mean "...beru*f*t sich der Frontsänger auf *ein* Interview..."? Your comment is not meaningful German so far.

Comment: @Emanuel Fair enough. Dies als Antwort auf eine zuvorgestellte Frage zu betrachten, war mir entgangen.

Comment: @arne.b No, *beruht* is absolutely fine. "Meine Aussage [beruht auf](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/beruhen) der Annahme, dass die vorliegenden Zahlen stimmen." Genau so kann ich auch "mich auf etwas beruhen", wie im Satz oben verwendet. Ich weiß nicht, was an dem Satz grammatikalisch auszusetzen ist. Ich persönlich würde einzig "einem" zu "ein" kürzen, was aber strikt gesehen grammatisch falsch ist und eben nur Umgangssprache ist.

Comment: @Em1 "beruhen" ist mE nicht reflexiv, daher kann möglicherweise ich auf etwas beruhen, aber nicht ich *mich* auf etwas beruhen; ebenso müsste in deinem Revolverheld-Beispiel das *sich* gestrichen würden. Aber auch dann ist mE "beruhen auf" nur für Abstrakta (Ideen, Theorien, Vermutungen, Entwicklungen, Phänomene, Ergebnisse, Wirkungen, ...) üblich und nicht für Personen.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware, that prepositions can be demanded by the following noun group or the verb.

The noun `interview` itself demands `in` when referring to its documented contents or `während` when referring to its course. As the contents of an interview are delivered during its course, there is little difference between both prepositions. In casual German, they can be used interchangeably in most cases.

Example, where only `in` is possible:

> *In* einem Interview mit Revolverheld steht, dass sie Musik machen.

Example, where `während` is preferable, but `in` still ok:

> *Während* eines Interviews mit Revolverheld stand der Sänger auf und sang „Alle meine Entchen“.

Example, where both prepositions are equally suitable:

> *In einem Interview* / *Während eines Interviews* mit Revolverheld sagt/sagte der Sänger, dass ihr nächster Song „Alle meine Entchen“ heißen wird.

You can see, that the preferable tense is different: The documentation of what he said referred to by `in` is present. The act of him saying it referred to by `während` is past.

Answer (score -2):

These sentences are actually different. They are both correct but mean different things.

*Auf einem Interview mit Revolverheld* means "in an interview" in the following sense: *Julia ist eine Journalistin. Sie ist auf einem Interview mit Revolverheld.* She's out there, doing the interview.

*In einem Interview mit Revolverheld* means "in an interview" in the following sense: *In einem Interview mit Revolverheld hat Johann gesagt, dass er Journalisten hasst." Here, Revolverheld is the interviewer. In an interview, where he was the interviewer, the interviewee said something-or-other.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: That's wrong. There are a lot of hits for "auf * Interview" but non for "[sein] auf * Interview".

Comment: See this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=auf+*+Interview%2Csein_INF+auf+ein+Interview%2Csein_INF+auf+das+Interview%2Csein_INF+auf+einem+Interview%2Csein_INF+auf+dieses+Interview&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cauf%20%2A%20Interview%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bauf%20das%20Interview%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bauf%20ein%20Interview%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bauf%20einem%20Interview%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bauf%20dieses%20Interview%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bauf%20die%20Interview%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bauf%20dem%20Interview%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bauf%20sein%20Interview%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: `auf einem Interview sein` could be used, but sounds strange. Maybe, it's common among journalists, but not among common people. I'd prefer `ein Interview durchführen/machen`.

Answer (score -3):

**Von, auf, in, bei, durch, mit, über, nach, wegen, gegen, um, an, für, vor, aus, unter, neben, seit, statt etc...**

they all work in different contexts.

Comment: I often read auf and in.

Comment: @DerPolyglott33... "in" is the standard preposition if you want to convey where some information can be found. All the others are for situations, causes and conditions. You can only read something "in" an interview, if that's what you're after.

Comment: If i see the word "interview" with a different preposition, i'll let you guys know :)

Comment: Sorry, but this answer isn't helpful at all. Yes, the question in title is "What prepositions go with Interview" but for one I guess almost all prepositions are possible, for another only a few of those you mentioned are really common.

Comment: @Em1... they are all common because there are verbs that require them to connect an object. I can find you standard everyday German examples for each of them. Yes, the answer isn't all that helpful, but this was the question.